# Getting pixel coordinates efficiently in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, pixel

I would like to create a function in Matlab that, given an image, will allow one to select a pixel by clicking on it in the image and return the coordinates of the pixel. Ideally, one would be able to click on several pixels in the image in succession, and the function would store all the respective coordinates in a matrix. Is there a way to do this in Matlab?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html)

> Graphical input from mouse or cursor
>   Syntax

```
    [x,y] = ginput(n) 
    [x,y] = ginput 
    [x,y,button] = ginput(...)
```

> #### Description
>
> `[x,y] = ginput(n)` enables you to
>   identify n points from the current
>   axes and returns their x- and
>   y-coordinates in the x and y column
>   vectors. Press the Return key to
>   terminate the input before entering n
>   points.

Comment: But how do I specify a particular image to display on which to use this function?

Comment: @jake: "ginput raises crosshairs in the current axes". I.e. just display the image and then run `ginput`.

Comment: it might also help if you show the axis coordinates: `axis on` before you call GINPUT

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want:

```
A=imread('filename.jpg');
image(A)
[x,y]=ginput()
```