# How to get the mouse click position on Matlab figure axes?

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I want to click in a Matlab figure and find out the x and y position of the clicked position.

In a graph I think there is a way to click a point on the line and get it's x and y coordinates. How do I do the same if there is no graph plotted?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking when you say "How do I do the same if there is no graph plotted?". But you probably want to use ginput(). E.g. see here: [getting-pixel-coordinates-efficiently-in-matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541444/getting-pixel-coordinates-efficiently-in-matlab)

Comment: I want to click somewhere on an empty plot (I think matlab calls it axis and not figure, because figure(1) does not generate that white canvas on which a graph actually shows up). I want to predefine maximum and minimum limits of x and y coordinates for the axes and when I click on an empty area on the axes, I want to be able to store the x and y coordinates of the point in a variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have created the figure try

```
[x_coord, y_coord]=ginput(1);
```

So you get to click once on the figure (that's why the argument is one) and you will get the coordinates returned returned by the function [ginput()](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/ginput.html).

Answer (score 7):

Here's how to do it most elegantly:

```
function test

    % create test figure
    f = figure(1);

    % set function to call on mouse click
    set(f, 'WindowButtonDownFcn', @clicker);


end

% function called on mouse click in the figure
function clicker(h,~)


    get(h, 'selectiontype')
    % 'normal' for left moue button
    % 'alt' for right mouse button
    % 'extend' for middle mouse button
    % 'open' on double click

    get(h, 'currentpoint')
    % Current mouse location, in pixels from the lower left.
    % When the units of the figure are 'normalized', the
    % coordinates will be [0 0] inb lower left, and [1 1] in
    % the upper right.

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this would also work:

```
function [loc] = get_image_point (I)
    figure('name','Doubleclick to set location');imshow(I);
    [c r] = getpts(1);
    loc = int32([c r]);
    if size(loc,1)>1
        loc = [loc(1,1) loc(1,2)];
    end
    close all;
end
```

Stephan

Answer (score 0):

Notes: 
 - `getpts()` - is an "Image Processing Toolbox" function.
 - `ginput()` - waits for your mouse-click, halts execution till you've clicked, and only works when called.

whereas `get(h, 'currentpoint')` will work anytime, as long as your program is running.